# get a single textbox value from array of textbox jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of text inputs like this:

```
<input type="textbox" name="col[]">
<input type="textbox" name="col[]">
<input type="textbox" name="col[]">
```

They are generated at run time using an "add" button.

I can fetch textbox array values using

```
$('input[name="col[]"]').each(function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

But if I just need 2nd textbox value then will I fetch it directly without looping through array using jquery?

I appreciate someones help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `.eq()` to select it:

```
var $textboxes = $('input[name="col[]"]')

var value1 = $textboxes.eq(0).val();
var value2 = $textboxes.eq(1).val();
...
```